# The composition of optimal transport maps is no longer an optimal transport map

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, differential-geometry, optimal-transport

Let $X,Y,Z$ be metric spaces. Let $\mu,\nu,\omega$ be the probability measures on $X,Y,Z$, respectively. Moreover, assume all three measures vanish on small sets. Assume $T:X\to Y$ is the optimal transport map from $\mu$ to $\nu$, i.e., $\nu=T\#\mu$; and $S:Y\to Z$ is the optimal transport map from $\nu$ to $\omega$.

I wonder if $T\circ S$ is the optimal transport map from $\mu$ to $\omega$. I know the statement is true when $X=Y=Z=\mathbb{R}$ where the optimal transport map between distributions of two 1-d random variables can be analytically expressed. Moreover, the statement is false if the measures are discrete in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d\geq 2$. But, how about the general case? Is there somehow a gluing lemma here?

Comment: Why the differential geometry tag?

Comment: OT is connected to maps in over manifolds, so I used that tag. Is there any issue with that?

Comment: Up to now, I have only a partial answer to this. In Wasserstein-2 space, such measures are called compatible measures. That is, if the transport maps among $\nu_0,\nu_{1/2},\nu_1$ satisfy $t_{\nu_0}^{\nu_1} = t_{\nu_{1/2}}^{\nu_1}\circ t_{\nu_0}^{\nu_1{/2}}$. For example, Gaussian measures are compatible if their covariance matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable. You may find some more examples in section 2.3.2 in An Invitation to Statistics
in Wasserstein Space.

Comment: The answer is definite if we are considering the quadratic cost and $X=Y=Z = \mathbb{R}^d$. Using Brenier's theorem says that a transport map is optimal between $\mu \in \mathcal{P}_{ac}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\nu := T\#\mu$ if and only if it is of the form $T:=\nabla \varphi$, where $\varphi :\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex. Thus, if $T\circ S$ is still the gradient of some convex function, we may give a definite answer.